# Rails InvalidAuthenticityToken only in one case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, csrf-protection

Experiencing a really strange problem with csrf tags, I can't pin down. Here is the strange behavior:

1. If I manually enter the address for a form page, `http://localhost:port/form_page`, everthing works fine.
2. If I submit the form and there are errors, I redirect back to the form_page with errors, and everything works fine.
3. BUT, if I click on a link I created on another page with `href='http://localhost:port/form_page'`, and then submit the form, I get an InvalidAuthenticityToken.
4. If I click on the link as in 3, then refresh the page before submitting, the form submits fine.

Not sure what I can change, since the form and controller appear to be good and are the same used in every case, but only fails in 25% of the cases above.

Comment: try adding `data: { turbolinks: false }` to `link_to`

Comment: I am using a raw html a tag for this, but tried `<%= link_to 'Form', controller: 'my_controller', action: 'form_page', tubrolinks: false %>` but with no success. Anything else I can do to help troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Change ‘turbolinks: false’ to ‘data: {turbolinks: false}’

Comment: Tried this too. No luck. Still need to manually refresh the page.